# how to find that whici variable has larger value and assign it to max var in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have two variable for graph one is value and other is value1 i want that int max should get the value of those variable which has maximum values like if value=50 and value1=100 then max=value1

```
    appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

     int value3=[appDelegate.oneGlobal intValue];
    int value4=[appDelegate.twoGlobal intValue];
    int value5=[appDelegate.threeGlobal intValue];


        int max;

        if (value3>value4) {
            max=value3;

        }  
        else if(value3>value5){

            max=value3;


          }
        else if(value4>value3){
            max=value4;

        }
        else if(value4>value5){

            max=value4;

        }
        else{
            max=value5;

        }
```

Comment: are you serious? wouldnt a simple if value > value 1, max = value, else max = value1 wont do?

Comment: your code will fail. Imagine the following: value3 = 10, value 4 = 5, value 5 = 20. Your `max` will be set to 10. And I'd recommend you searching a bit in the internet. And read the books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all your `if-statements` and add the following to your code:

```
max = (value3 > value4) ? value3: value4;
max = (max > value5) ? max: value5;
```

That would do the trick.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

Use `MAX()`:

```
int max = MAX(MAX(value3, value4), value5);
```